# header with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

If I redirect from one domain to another, can I send headers with the response. I've been trying to do it by:

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect("http://localhost:9000")
response['session_key'] = request.session.session_key
return response
```

This didn't seem to work. The server is running on localhost:8000. I'm trying to use the session id like a token (It's a hack.), but haven't been able to.

Comment: I just tested with Django 1.8, and Django does set the header in the response, even when using `HttpResponseRedirect`. Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: I was serving angular app through grunt on localhost:9000. My Django project used to be a server rendered web app, but recently I've made another app for a restful API. My backend uses a custom session based authentication. I've been trying to stick with the same auth. Since I plan on serving the angular app through CDN or another domain later, I tried this hack, but I didn't see session_key in the response header. I planned on associating the session_key header in the incoming requests to associate the appropriate session with the request.